# calling hive -e from a python script

Tags: python, hive, cloudera-cdh

I would like to run a very simple hive command from within my python script. I am trying to use hive -e, but I am getting an error

```
def hive():
    cmd = "hive -e \"msck repair table dashboard_report\""
    print(cmd)
    check_call(cmd)
```

This is the error I am getting

```
hive -e "msck repair table dashboard_report"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/yosi/work/source/slg/tiger/src/main/resources/python/tiger.py", line 59, in <module>
hive()
File  "/home/yosi/work/source/slg/tiger/src/main/resources/python/tiger.py", line 57, in hive
check_call(cmd)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 535, in check_call
retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: What does `check_call` do exactly?

Comment: create a new process and check its return code

Comment: Can you please post the code?

Comment: Run your command from the command line first. Do this from the same directory from which you start your Python program. Does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your check_call function is calling `subprocess.Popen`. If you want to pass arguments to that function you have to pass them in a list.

Probably:

```
cmd = ["hive", "-e", "\"msck repair table dashboard_report\""]
check_call(cmd)
```

Will work. Maybe some refactoring will be needed down the call stack to accept a list instead of a string.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python2.7 then the below code snippet will work.

```
import subprocess
command = [""" hive -e "msck repair table dashboard_report" """]
print subprocess.check_output(command,shell=True)
```